Aviation headset amplifier
What type of amplifier is on the market or can I use to get my microphone to work? I am converting a British combat headset to use in an open cockpit airplane. Right now current headsets just don't work well with an open cockpit.
I have about a dozen of these combat headsets that are perfect for loud environments and have active noise-cancelling. I have gotten everything to work but the microphone. Currently I have a 9 V running the active noise cancellation through an amplifier to bring it to 24 V and then everything else hooked directly up. The problem I'm having is the microphone is almost picking up nothing. It looks to be a 150 Ω speaker type microphone. I think the issue is it needs an amplifier.
My David Clark headset is 50 Ω impedance microphone. Any suggestions on an amplifier or if I'm missing something. I have pictures of a disassembled microphone for reference. It's a little mangled, but still good reference.




Please write a specific question

I added my question to the beginning and it was asked at the bottom but I forgot to word it better.

From the photos it appears that is a dynamic microphone; you can see the plastic diaphragm, the end of the voice coil, and there will be a permanent magnet surrounding the coil. It has a much lower output than a modern, electret condenser microphone that would be found in your David Clark headset. Search for "dynamic microphone preamplifier" and you'll find what you need. They are available as small modules, with or without a box.
Don't forget the possibility that the microphones in those old British combat headset could be damaged -- torn diaphragm, moisture causing corrosion, voice coil rubbing, magnet losing it's strength.

The headsets are brand new. I worked for a defense company who was scraping them. I found some preamps that will probably work and they use the bias power from the aircraft. If it is not enough I'll try a LM386 powered preamp. Let me know if you think these will work. https://www.ruggedradios.com/products/dynamic-microphone-preamplifier

Normally you'd want a mic preamp to have low noise, but in this application with the mic next to your mouth that isn't as important. So all you need is a preamp with enough gain.

Those amps get here this week. I'll get them soldered in and report back. Appreciate all the comments from the old answer that got deleted and your answer.

Reporting back and this preamp worked flawlessly. It's actually extremely good and all the sensitivities had to be turned down on my radio. No excess noise and it's all put in a nice 3D printed box and attached to the plane. Thanks for all the help

We appreciate the followup!
